# converting request.querystring using toString()

Tags: javascript, tostring

In JScript, why do I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method" when I try to convert request.querystring to a string using toString()?

```
var params = Request.QueryString;

var params = params.toString();
```

Background info:

I'm trying to convert the querystring to a string so that I can perform a regex replace and remove certain items when they appear in the url.

```
var param = param.replace(/([?&])(allow)=[\w-]+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently discovered the solution to this problem.

```
var params = Request.QueryString;

should be:

var params = Request.QueryString.Item;
```

There is no need to convert params to a string after that to manipulate the query string.  Further you have access to everything in the query string by calling Request.QueryString("param").Item.

Example:

```
http://www.mysite.com?q=query&name=george

var name = Request.QueryString("name").Item;
```

Comment: My coworkers have been working with JScript for years and I have never seen use of .Item. This is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know -- weird Microsoft JScript implementation.

I had the same problem.

```
var strParams = new String(params);
```

seems to work though.